# With Ubuntu 21.04, can Openbox be customized like the Openbox of other distros (eg BunsenLabs)?

Tags: openbox

I'm using Ubuntu because it's easy to dual boot with my particular laptop. Other distros brick my laptop. Not sure why.

For WM, I'm used to Openbox. Used to use BunsenLabs.

As I'm getting Openbox installed on my box, I'm hitting some dead ends.

- OBMenu has missing dependencies with some seeming to be incompatible with the current Ubuntu setup.
- lxappearance crashes. How can I change the icons and gtk theme?
- Shortcuts like "gnome-session-quit" don't work. CrunchBang(#!) and BunsenLabs have some scripts like gnome-session-quit but I'm not sure how to install stuff like that.

Has anyone had success getting these things running on their Ubuntu setup?

Comment: Yes `openbox` can be customized; as it's a critical package supported by Lubuntu (https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/packagesets/hirsute/lubuntu) but note we don't use LXDE and haven't since *bionic* so GTK makes no sense.. we use LXQt so we maintain it for that. OBMenu isn't a Lubuntu package, so will be upstream Debian's

Comment: in fact `obmenu` hasn't been available since *bionic* (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=obmenu&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) so what `obmenu` where you trying to use?  (I see `obmenu` only available for *precise, trusty, xenial & bionic*)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the replies. I'm using Ubuntu, so I'm a little confused by Lubuntu's relevance. I don't have a lot of experience with Ubuntu/Lubuntu. For BunsenLabs, I would use obmenu and lxappearance to change themes. Are those not compatible with Ubuntu? Is bionic a replacement for obmenu?

Comment: `lxappearance` is a LXDE program, which was supported by Lubuntu until 18.04 for Ubuntu; however with LXDE using *deprecated* & almost completely unmaintained GTK2; Lubuntu followed LXDE devs to LXQt (Qt5) thus LXDE apps are no longer maintained by the Lubuntu team on later releases. `openbox` is still a package we maintain as we still use it (and we concentrate on it's use with LXQt now, not deprecated LXDE).  Key is you're talking about 'universe' packages, ie. community supported; they `lxappearance` **was**, `openbox` **is** Lubuntu package in Ubuntu, but yes available for all.

Comment: `obmenu` needs `python2` so it's gone (as was anything else not ported to `python3` in Debian & Ubuntu. Python2 is EOL if you didn't know; https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/   thus I asked where you got `obmenu`...   fyi:  I'm using Lubuntu *impish* now, but I still consider my box a Ubuntu one...

Answer (score 0):

Yes `openbox` can be customized; as it's a critical package supported by Lubuntu ([https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-archive/packagesets/hirsute/lubuntu](https://people.canonical.com/%7Eubuntu-archive/packagesets/hirsute/lubuntu)) but note we don't use LXDE and haven't since bionic so GTK makes no sense.. we use LXQt so we maintain it for that. OBMenu isn't a Lubuntu package, so will be upstream Debian's.

In fact `obmenu` hasn't been available since bionic (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=obmenu&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) so what obmenu where you trying to use? (I see obmenu only available for *precise*, *trusty*, *xenial* & *bionic*)

`obmenu` needs `python2` so it's gone (*as was anything else not ported to python3 in Debian & Ubuntu*. Python2 is EOL if you didn't know; https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/ thus I asked where you got obmenu...

fyi: I'm using Lubuntu *impish* now, but I still consider my box a Ubuntu one...

`lxappearance` is a LXDE program, which was supported by Lubuntu until 18.04 for Ubuntu; however with LXDE using deprecated & almost completely unmaintained GTK2; Lubuntu followed LXDE devs to LXQt (Qt5) thus LXDE apps are no longer maintained by the Lubuntu team on later releases.

`openbox` is still a package we maintain as we still use it (and we concentrate on it's use with LXQt now, not deprecated LXDE). Key is you're talking about 'universe' packages, ie. community supported; `lxappearance` **was** a Lubuntu package, `openbox` still **is** a Lubuntu package in Ubuntu, but yes they are available for all to download and use.